# springsecurity with grails - how to deny login for users that are deleted using a logical deleted property

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using grails 2.2.2 and spring-security-core:2.0-RC2

My domain User object does not actually get deleted from the database - instead i set a property called "deleted" to true.

The problem is: how can I stop spring security from granting successful login attempts to a user id that is marked as deleted?

I'd like to be able to support creating a new user with a previously deleted name.

Burt Beckwith's answer below got me on the track of checking out overriding the spring security bean implementaions.

I've tried overriding a couple of the methods in the userDetailsService bean and springSecurityService with my implementations as shown below (all I did was use the same parent class implementation but change the User.findWhere() methods to use deleted: false).

I've also added these bean definitions to resources.groovy but i find that sometimes the original SpringSecurityService.getCurrentUser() method is called instead of my implementation.  (If i change the spring security source to my implementation this all works fine, but I'd rather use an override so future version upgrades don't break).

```
class MySpringSecurityService extends SpringSecurityService {
    @Override
    Object getCurrentUser() {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            return null
        }

        String className = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName
        String usernamePropName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName
        grailsApplication.getClassForName(className).findWhere(
                    (usernamePropName): principal.username, 
                    deleted: false)
    }
}

class MyUserDetailsService extends GormUserDetailsService {
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        String userClassName = conf.userLookup.userDomainClassName
        def dc = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(userClassName)
        if (!dc) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified user domain class '$userClassName' is not a domain class")
        }

        Class<?> User = dc.clazz

        User.withTransaction { status ->
            def user = User.findWhere((conf.userLookup.usernamePropertyName): username, deleted: false)
            if (!user) {
                log.warn "User not found: $username"
                throw new NoStackUsernameNotFoundException()
           }

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = loadAuthorities(user, username, loadRoles)
            createUserDetails user, authorities
        }
    }
}
```

My resources.groovy looks something like this:

```
beans = {
    userDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService)
    springSecurityService(MySpringSecurityService) {
        authenticationTrustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
        grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
        passwordEncoder = ref('passwordEncoder')
        objectDefinitionSource = ref('objectDefinitionSource')
        userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
        userCache = ref('userCache')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested, but should work or be very close to working.

You'll need to override the logic in the `preAuthenticationChecks` Spring bean that the plugin registers. The default implementation does the `isAccountNonLocked()`, `isEnabled()`, and `isAccountNonExpired()` checks, so you can subclass it and add your check(s):

```
package com.foo.bar

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusException

class MyPreAuthenticationChecks extends DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks {

   private static final EXCEPTION = new DeletedException()

   void check(UserDetails user) {

      // do the standard checks
      super.check user

      // then the custom check(s)
      if (user.deleted) {
         log.debug 'User account is deleted'
         throw EXCEPTION
      }
   }

   static class DeletedException extends AccountStatusException {
      LockedException() {
         super('User account is deleted')
      }

      // avoid the unnnecessary cost
      Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
         this
      }
   }
}
```

Put this in a subdirectory of your /src/groovy directory corresponding to the package you choose, and register yours in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
import com.foo.bar.MyPreAuthenticationChecks

beans = {
   preAuthenticationChecks(MyPreAuthenticationChecks)
}
```

Note that the "user" instance you'll be working with is a `UserDetails` instance, not the domain class instance that is loaded to populate the `UserDetails`. So to have access to the `deleted` property you'll also need a custom `UserDetailsService`. This is easy and a common enough thing to do that it has its own chapter in the docs: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/userDetailsService.html

Note that having the exception as a static inner class, using a singleton, and overriding the `fillInStackTrace` method are all optional and independent of this question. You can put it in its own top-level class if you prefer (it makes sense to me to keep it internal since it's unlikely to be used outside of this class). You can also create a new instance each time, but there's no difference between instances (there's no useful state) so that's not needed. I override to `fillInStackTrace` to avoid incurring the cost of filling all those stack frames when they're not going to be needed at all.

Comment: This looks really promising, but I'm worried it won't cover one case: what if i create a user with username xyz, then delete it.  Then create another new user with the same username xyz.  I would like to support that case.  It seems like this fix will only check for the deleted flag after looking up the user object from the database.  I would like the query that looks in the database for the username to just exclude records where deleted = true.  I'm looking into the UserDetailsService that you mentioned for this, but I haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: `UserDetailsService` is definitely the place for that - just add the extra criteria to the query to exclude deleted users.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but if it serves somebody, here it is:

Just simplifying Burt Beckwith's answer, if you just want to throw the same exception as if the user does not exist, you can just extend `DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks` like this (where Person is the table with the users), and there is no need for a custom `UserDetailsService`:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import  org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

class MyPreAuthenticationChecks extends DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks {

  void check(UserDetails user) {

    // do the standard checks
    super.check user

    if (Person.findByUsername(user.getUsername())?.deleted){
        log.debug("Wrong credentials");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong credentials");
    }
  }
}
```